# Lock crontab / make it write-protected

Tags: cron, mate

I am currently trying to build a thin-client with a Raspberry Pi 2 based on Ubuntu MATE 15.04. I needed to write a command in the user's crontab (`mate-session-save` didn't work with root's crontab) and I don't want them to change that.

In theory they can't change that because there is no easy way to open a terminal window, but still I want to know: Is it possible to make crontab write-protected? I know you can deny it for specific users.

Comment: Do you want to prevent them from adding more cronjobs or simply removing yours?

Comment: Ideally both, no adding, no deleting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a cronjob for a user that they can't modify, it is easy. Just create an executable file in `/etc/cron.d`, with the sixth field being the username and the seventh field the command (same format as in `/etc/crontab`). For example:

```
$ cat /etc/cron.d/foo
30 5 * * * muru date > /tmp/foo
```

Will run `date > /tmp/foo` as user `muru` at 5:30 each day.

If you want to prevent users from modifying their crontab, add their username to `/etc/cron.deny`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try that tomorrow, looks good :)